# Add custom Markers that will be shown in the Goto Symbol (Cmd+R) window

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I've posted this exact same question in the ST forum plugin dev threads

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/add-custom-markers-that-will-be-shown-in-the-goto-symbol-cmd-r-window/23772

I've been using ST for a couple of years,

I'd like some guidance in first knowing if want I want to accomplish is possible through a plugin development, and if the answer is positive, maybe some reference as to where to start looking to develop this feature.

I would like to include some kind of marker that when placed in code, it includes a new entry in the list that is displayed in the Goto Symbol (Cmd+R) window. The closest example I have now is from Xcode, where in the source code you can include a comment with the "MARK:" keyword and it will render a new section in the top header bar of the editor (which is the equivalent of the goto symbol in ST).

When working with large files this feature would be of tremendous help because it allows to organize the blocks of code based on custom criteria regarding the logical relationships around it and not just the sequence of functions that exist in the file.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the symbol list is controlled by a preferences file that tells sublime what scopes should appear in the symbol list for any given language and, optionally, what transformations should be done for display purposes (e.g. to indent the methods in a class).

Such configuration files are `tmPreferences` files (XML files in Plist format) within a package and which are generally named with names that start with `Symbol List`. For example, `Packages/C++/Symbol List.tmPreferences` is one of such files for use in the C++ package (which covers, C, C++ and both flavors of Objective-C). Since the files are Plist files the actual names don't matter, but this is a convention that makes such files easier to find.

There is some [documentation on symbols](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/symbols.html) you can read for more information.

Trivially, if you save the following XML into `Packages/C++/Symbol List Pragma.tmPreferences` it will add all of the `#pragma MARK` lines in your  source files to the symbol list (current file only), replacing `#pragma MARK` with `" ---- "`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Symbol List</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>(source.c | source.c++ | source.objc | source.objc++) &amp; (meta.preprocessor.c)</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>showInSymbolList</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>showInIndexedSymbolList</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>symbolTransformation</key>
        <string>
            s/#pragma MARK/ ---- /g;
        </string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This doesn't get you all the way there; for one thing, `#ifdef` and `#endif` directives are caught with this rule. Additionally it doesn't visually indent everything that follows which IIRC XCode does. However, it's a good starting point for seeing what is going on.

If you wanted to actually do this with special single line comments and not a `#pragma` I believe you would need to enhance the syntax highlighting for the language(s) you're targetting to match such comments and give them a scope that you can uniquely target.